# Subsetting data from multiple CSV files with missing headings in R

Tags: r, csv

I have data from actigraphy devices in multiple CSV files. I want to subset three rows from these files and merge them together in a data frame.

The problem is that the first row has data only in the first column (think 1A in Excel), but some rows have data in 13 columns. Thus several column names are missing.

I first tried combining all csv files like this:

```
file.list <- list.files(pattern='*.csv')
df.list <- sapply(file.list, read.csv, simplify=FALSE)

library(dplyr)
df <- bind_rows(df.list, .id = "id")
```

The second command here gives a "duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed" error. I tried adding the `row.names=NULL` argument but this results in "no lines available in input" error message.

For an individual data file I was able to achieve the wanted result by naming the columns first and then subsetting the data:

```
test <- read.csv("test3.csv",header=FALSE)

names(test) <-c("Column.A","Column.B","Column.C","Column.D","Column.E","Column.F","Column.G",
                "Column.H","Column.I","Column.J","Column.K", "Column.L", "Column.M")

bar <- subset(test, Column.A =="Identity:" | Column.A == "Interval Type"| Column.A == "Sleep Summary" & Column.B == "Average(n)")
```

How could I repeat a similar process to all csv files in a given folder?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply extend your function in `sapply`. In fact, use the *col.names* argument of `read.csv` and use `LETTERS` vector in a `paste0` call. Furthermore, use `%in%` operator in your `subset`:

```
df.list <- sapply(file.list, function(f) {
              # READ DATA AND ASSIGN COL NAMES
              tmp <- read.csv(f, header=FALSE, col.names = paste0("Column.", LETTERS[1:13])

              # SUBSET DATA
              bar <- subset(tmp, Column.A %in% c("Identity:", "Interval Type") |
                                 Column.A == "Sleep Summary" & Column.B == "Average(n)")
           }, simplify=FALSE)


final_df <- do.call(rbind, df.list)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do this by defining a helper function to perform multiple operations on each file. This works under the assumption that each file has an equal number of columns, with the same `names` as defined in your `names` vector.

```
library(tidyverse)

readFile <- function(file){
    df <- read.csv(file, header=FALSE)
    names(df) <-c("Column.A","Column.B","Column.C","Column.D","Column.E","Column.F","Column.G",
                "Column.H","Column.I","Column.J","Column.K", "Column.L", "Column.M")
    df <- subset(df, Column.A =="Identity:" | Column.A == "Interval Type"| Column.A == "Sleep Summary" & Column.B == "Average(n)")
    return(df)
}

file.list <- list.files(pattern='*.csv')
df.list <- sapply(file.list, readFile, simplify=FALSE) %>% bind_rows()
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you need clean your data before

You can use a library named "SQLDF" and query your 3 Dataframes (CSV) library instead!

For example:
I made a example supposing we have 3 dataframes, so you can get the columns you need.

[image]

I hope this helps!